# Tic Tac Toe Turn change with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, tic-tac-toe

So I have this code to the main loop for the game , everything seems to go as intended except turn change, i am not sure what is the problem i have been stuck in this for 2 days and can't figure it out here is the link to the full script in case anyone want to check if i did something wrong in the functions itself https://github.com/AmrBinBashir/Tic-Tac-Toe-Pygame:

```
run = True
while run:
    draw_board_onetime(board_boxes, win)
    make_board(board_boxes)
    board = [" "] * 10
    game_on = True
    while game_on:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for box in board_boxes:
                    if box.is_hover(pos):
                        box.hovered = True
                        box.draw(win)
                    else:
                        box.hovered = False
                        box.draw(win)
            turn = "player1"
            if turn == "player1":
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    for i in range(1, 10):
                        if board_boxes[i].is_hover(pos):
                            board_boxes[i].text = x_marker
                            board[i] = x_marker
                            print(board)
                            if check_win(board, x_marker):
                                game_on = False  # WIN
                            else:
                                if full_board_check(board):
                                    game_on = False  # TIE
                                else:
                                    turn = "player2"
            else:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    for i in range(1, 10):
                        if board_boxes[i].is_hover(pos):
                            board_boxes[i].text = o_marker
                            board[i] = o_marker
                            print(board)
                            if check_win(board, o_marker):
                                game_on = False  # WIN
                            else:
                                if full_board_check(board):
                                    game_on = False  # TIE
                                else:
                                    turn = "player1"

        pygame.display.update()
    sys.exit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: You set turn to player1 every loop

Comment: Move the initialization `turn = "player1"` before `while game_on:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about your code (haven't executed it myself) but I'm pretty sure overriding

```
turn = "player1"
#will always slip into:
        if turn == "player1":
```

Move setting "player1" somewhere else in your code, e.g. a global variable for testing. Right now it seems that even if you set it to "player2" it will be overwritten anyway in the next run.

---

Little extra bit, kind advice: Strings don't make good comparators. Unless you enjoy the readability, think about using booleans or at least integers for that matter. You will learn later on how they are much more versatile and less prone to errors (such as simple typos or accidental capitalisation).

Booleans for example can easily be flipped like 
`player = not player` (switching back and forth between `True` for P1 and `False` for P2).

Integers can easily be incremented like `player_id += 1` (which starts becoming handy for a board game with 3 players or more).

Comment: Thanks for the advice about booleans , i will try to use booleans more often in my code  and the solution was to just make the variable out side the game_on loop .

Comment: Awesome! Good luck and don't get held back by those little mistakes, everyone makes them

Answer (score 0):

The solution if anyone sees this in the feature, simply moving the turn variable outside of the game_on loop so it cannot be overridden every loop

```
run = True
while run:
    draw_board_onetime(board_boxes, win)
    make_board(board_boxes)
    board = [" "] * 10
    game_on = True
    turn = 'player1'
    while game_on:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for box in board_boxes:
                    if box.is_hover(pos):
                        box.hovered = True
                        box.draw(win)
                    else:
                        box.hovered = False
                        box.draw(win)

            if turn == "player1":
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    for i in range(1, 10):
                        if board_boxes[i].is_hover(pos):
                            board_boxes[i].text = x_marker
                            board[i] = x_marker
                            print(board)
                            if check_win(board, x_marker):
                                game_on = False  # WIN
                            else:
                                if full_board_check(board):
                                    game_on = False  # TIE
                                else:
                                    turn = "player2"
            else:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    for i in range(1, 10):
                        if board_boxes[i].is_hover(pos):
                            board_boxes[i].text = o_marker
                            board[i] = o_marker
                            print(board)
                            if check_win(board, o_marker):
                                game_on = False  # WIN
                            else:
                                if full_board_check(board):
                                    game_on = False  # TIE
                                else:
                                    turn = "player1"

        pygame.display.update()
    sys.exit()
sys.exit()
```